# Очень странная проблема с рендерингом хелпера HiddenFor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Есть строго-типизорованное представление TestView.
Класс модели представления содержит ID и еще несколько свойств.
Вплоть до передачи ViewModel на предсталение, ID имеет одно значение (5 например),
но в результате генериться поле с другим значением (10).
Не могу понять, в чем дело.

Comment: Я не шарю в ASP.NET, но в любом случае, кода в твоём посте нет, а должен быть.

Comment: Дело тут даже не в коде. Точнее, не в моём, а в коде хелпера. Мой выглядит так:
Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.ID), где ID==5, дебаггером проходил — совпадает. Но в результате генерит не то, что надо <input id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="10" /><script>alert("Уязвимость detected");</script>

Comment: в одной из многих `Best Practices` по ASP.NET MVC я читал нечто следующие:

> Используйте HTML там, где это возмножно

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут описание проблемы

[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx](http://goo.gl/WB84a)

Нужно делать **ModelState.Clear()**;